# Conversion of element text via async AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, async-await

I'm having an issue with some asynchronous functions that seem to act out of order. The script below triggers a `forEach` on a small number of elements, and performs an AJAX request to an API to get the user name by using the user ID from the original element `innerHTML`, and updates the text.

The issue is around the `users` object that I want to store previously fetched user names in, and bypass the need to do subsequent AJAX calls for the same user. I have tried making the `forEach` callback async and awaiting that, as well as the `window.onload` but the script always seems to trigger all AJAX calls rather than waiting like I expect.

```js
// The object that stores user names that are fetched from API
const users = {};

const getUserName = async (userId) => {
  // Return the saved user name if it is stored already
  if (users[userId]) {
    return users[userId];
  }

  // Calls the API to get the name of the user
  const response = await fetch(
    `/user/${userId}/`,
  );
  const userName = await response.text();

  // Store the user name to prevent duplicate calls
  users[userId] = userName;
  return userName;
};

const convertNameNode = async (nameNode) => {
  const userId = nameNode.innerHTML;
  const userName = await getUserName(userId);

  // Replace the text in the DOM, e.g. from 1 to 'Steve'
  nameNode.innerHTML = userName;
};

// On load, trigger conversion of user IDs to user names
window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.userId').forEach(node => {
    convertNameNode(node);
  });
};
```

Comment: if you want your requests to occur one after the other, then you can use `.onload = async () => {`, and use a for loop instead of forEach: `for(const node of querySelectorAll(...)) {await convertNameNode(node)}`

Answer (score 0):

Since `fetch()` is async (read: *"Since `fetch()` returns a promise"*), but you try to assign the response text of `fetch()` to your cache object, your cache will be empty until the server has responded - which will happen long after your `.forEach()` loop is done.

So instead of storing the response text of the fetch promise in the cache, you need to store the promise itself:

```js
const users = {};

const getUserName = (userId) => {
  if (!users[userId]) {
    console.log(`requesting name for ID ${userId}...`);
    users[userId] = fetch(`/user/${userId}/`).then(r => r.text());
  }
  return users[userId];
};

const convertNameNode = async (nameNode) => {
  nameNode.innerHTML = await getUserName(nameNode.innerHTML);
};

const test = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.userId').forEach(convertNameNode);
};

test();

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
// mockup fetch
function randInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function fetch(url) {
  const userId = url.split('/')[2];
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({
    text: () => "Username for " + userId
  }), randInt(250, 1000)));
}
```

```html
<div class="userId">1</div>
<div class="userId">2</div>
<div class="userId">3</div>
<div class="userId">1</div>
<div class="userId">2</div>
<div class="userId">3</div>
<div class="userId">4</div>
```

Notes

- `getUserName()` does not need to be `async` anymore, because it does not need to wait for anything. It creates promises and returns promises - waiting is the job of the caller.
- I'm using `fetch().then(r => r.text());` to convert the result of the fetch promise to string.
  In fetch, the response `.text()` can only be read *once*, because it's a stream and trying to read a steam twice will result in an error. But promises remember their result value indefinitely, i.e. the same promise can be `await`ed multiple times with the same result. So I'm using `.then()` to change the overall promise result to the value of `.text()`. This way `await getUserName(1)` will always produce a string - exactly what I need from a cache.
- `getUserName()` could be reduced to

  ```
  const getUserName = uid => users[uid] || users[uid] = fetch(`/user/${uid}/`).then(r => r.text());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not waiting for the fetch operation to finish to start the new operation.

Here is how I would do it.

> Solution 1 wait and calls each value.

```js
// On load, trigger conversion of user IDs to user names
window.onload = async () => {
  var nodes =  document.querySelectorAll('.userId');
  for(var i=0; i< nodes.length; i++){
    await convertNameNode(nodes[i]); // wait here, before processing the next node
  }
```

> Solution 2 calls multilabel value at the same time with cache
> Your current code should work except that some changes has to be made on the onLoad

```js
const convertNameNode = async (nameNode, nodeList) => {
  const userId = nameNode.innerHTML;
  const userName = await getUserName(userId); 
  // Replace the text in the DOM, e.g. from 1 to 'Steve' for all userId with 1
  nodes.filter(x=> x.innerHTML === userId).forEach(x=> {
      x.innerHTML = userName;
  });
};

// On load, trigger conversion of user IDs to user names
window.onload = () => {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.userId');
  // loop only throw a distinct userId
  nodes.reduce((acc, value)=> {
    if (!acc.find(x=> x.innerHTML == value.innerHTML))
        acc.push(value);
        return acc;
  },[]).forEach(node => {
    convertNameNode(node, nodes);
  });
```

Comment: That is counter-productive for performance, because it effectively serializes all the the requests that could run in parallel.

Comment: It is what he wanted right??? and there will not be an issue with the performance when there is less then 10000 calls. It will be very fast  anyway. I could solve it in another way but this way is less complicated and more right for the current issue.

Comment: No, what he wanted was not to daisy-chain all requests, he wanted to have a functioning cache.

Comment: This is what OP wrote my friend. `but the script always seems to trigger all AJAX calls rather than waiting like I expect.`

Comment: That's because the OP expected the wrong thing. He did not understand the timing implications of his code. He clearly intends to have a `users` cache to prevent duplicate requests. Sure, making things practically synchronous might solve the timing issues of asynchronous code, but it's certainly not an ideal approach. If your code was applied to 100 unique user IDs, and on average it would take 100 ms to resolve one ID, we would end up at 100 * 100 = 10.000 ms = 10 s of time. Chrome has a request concurrency of 6 (I think) , so we would end up at 10/6 = 1.6 s with a proper concurrent solution.

Comment: If there were only 5 or so IDs to resolve, the OP would probably not try to implement a cache in the first place. So it's reasonable to assume that they have a couple more, and that they actually do care about performance.

Comment: Hmm you may be right. Will update my answer and add the other solution which will make the async work.

Comment: Well What do you think about solution 2 @Tomalak

Comment: Well it's a lot more complicated now ... andit still does not use a cache. :) So the next time you want to resolve user IDs, e.g. when new nodes are added to the page—think "log viewer", or "chat application"—or when you need a username in some different area of the application, you'd still be forced to make duplicate requests.

Comment: `getUserName` cache in the right way and its already working for him. The problem he is having is calling duplicated userId on the same time and that causes that the fetch operation for the previous calls on userId for example 1 calls again before the fetch operation for userId 1 is finished and that is why the cash operation is not working. All you did in your solution is set up a settimeout act exactly as my solution 1 well not exactly but is almost the same way. My solution 2 will work the next time the fetch operation for userId 1 is called the cache operation will work then.

Comment: No, all I did in my solution was to simulate a `fetch()` operation that takes X milliseconds of time, for the the sole purpose of having something to show when "Run code snippet" is clicked, and use a working cache. My code is actually *simpler* than the OP's original code (and a lot simpler than your's), and it's reusable outside of the single-shot for-each/`node.innerHTML` context. Your code will not work outside of that context, and it does not use a cache.

Comment: agree to disagree I do not care about cache. `getUserName` already using it.

Comment: Agree to disagree as much as you like. Your code is not using a cache. It does not send duplicate requests for usernames *in a single shot*. That's not the same thing.